# What are these strange domain-name GET requests in my webserver?

Tags: ubuntu, web-server

I recently created a new webserver, and after a day of activity I've noticed strange GET requests in my server logs. They look like complete domains instead of normal URL paths.

[image: logs]

Can someone tell me what these requests are, if they're dangerous and (if so) how to safeguard against them? I'm running Ubuntu, NGinx, uWSGI, Flask and Python 3.

Comment: They're probably looking for open proxies.

Comment: I agree with @ceejayoz. Question: are you running your server on port 8080 by any chance? You want to make sure you don't (accidentally) have an open forward proxy running, or else people from around the world will start taking advantage of your server.